# Angular 6: image from assets not working in inline style

Tags: angular, angular-template

I'm using `Angular 6`.

I have to set background image of div from template and for that, I'm doing

```
<div class="full-page-background" [style.background-image]="'url(./assets/img/bg5.jpg)'">
</div>
```

But this gives **404** not found.

I tried same path with `<img>` tag

```
<img src="./assets/img/bg5.jpg" alt="">
```

and it's working fine.

**1. Why it's not working with style element?**
**2. How to set background image of div?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `ngStyle` directive

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-image':'url(./assets/img/bg5.jpg)'}">
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be as,

```
<div class="full-page-background" style="background-image: url('/assets/img/bg5.jpg'); "></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

using **style.backround** instead of style.background-image

```
<div class="full-page-background" [style.background]="'url(./assets/img/bg5.jpg)'">
</div>
```

or i think this also works

```
<div class="full-page-background" [style.backgroundImage]="'url(./assets/img/bg5.jpg)'">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you send me plunker or stackblitz with your code

Comment: using `../assets/img/bg5.jpg` worked. There is to add two dots.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom class bg:

Define class bg in css:

.bg{

```
background-image: url('/../assets/img/bg5.jpg');
```

}